# WebScriptEnablingBehavior in WCF service doesn't work with POST method

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, rest

I would like to take advantage of `WebScriptEnablingBehavior` in my WCF REST service to provide the ability to generate a javascript client proxy (and the strongly typed objects that go with it).
It works fine with the `GET` and `client.DownloadData()` method (parameters passed as query strings) but I'm struggling to make it work with `POST` and `client.UploadData(...)`.

The problem is that the parameters end-up both null in my service method (no error/exception, I can debug through it just fine... They're just null).

The `web.config` file

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="ServWS_Main_2.WS_Main_2">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="JSONOnly" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="ServWS_Main_2.IServWS" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JSONOnly">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The service contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServWS
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    ProviderInfo AddTo(string serviceName, BubbleInfo bubble);
}
```

The implementation

```
public class WS_Main_2 : IServWS
{
    public ProviderInfo AddTo(string serviceName, BubbleInfo bubble)
    {
        // at this point both serviceName and bubble  are null
    }
}
```

Definition of the complex type passed as parameter

```
[DataContract]
public class BubbleInfo
{

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

The call from the client

```
BubbleInfo bub = new BubbleInfo() { Text = "test2" };

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BubbleInfo));
serializer.WriteObject(stream, bub);

var url = GetURL() + "/addto?serviceName=MyService";
byte[] data = client.UploadData(url, "POST", stream.ToArray());
```

Note that it works fine if I don't use `WebScriptEnablingBehavior` but `webHttp` and `URITemplate` instead.
Tested with Visual Studio built-in web server as well as IIS Express 7.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the "body style" of the request message. You may be sending a 'bare' JSON message to the service when when the service actually expects a 'wrapped' message (with an extra wrapper around the JSON that is generally the parameter name.)

What you need to pay attention to is the `WebInvokeAttribute.BodyStyle` property. It gets and sets the body style of the messages that are sent to and from the service operation. It ocntrols whether to wrap requests and responses sent to and received from the service operation the attribute is applied to. Generally the returned JSON is wrapped by JavaScript function which can be executed cross-domain, so you may need to remove that by switching to a 'bare' body style.

What happens if you set the BodyStyle property on WebInvokeAttribute explicitly to Bare or to Wrapped, and try again? Does that fix the problem for you? I think it should!

Comment: I also think my problem is with the "unwrapped" JSON message. Also, since  WebScriptEnablingBehavior is geared to be used from ASP.NET Ajax and I was testing my service from a plain .NET C# program, it might be why. I tried all the different body styles to no avail (same result or service would not start).

Comment: That is very strange...do you have any details of the errors / traces that happen at the service side? I would enable full tracing and debugging, and set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults settings, and see what happens.